# How to make the v-stepper steps always visible on top of the page?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

In a Nuxt.js app using Vuetify.js framework, I have a `v-stepper` component which, when scrolling any page down, **its steps** become unvisible (I put the stepper component inside **pages/index.vue**). **I want them to remain always visible on top.**

For this purpose, I think only putting the `v-stepper` inside a `v-toolbar`  component can achieve the goal, but not really: no idea how to open the `v-stepper` component inside **layouts/default.vue** and close it inside **pages/index.vue**:

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar>
      <!-- open v-stepper here -->
      <v-stepper>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-content>
      <nuxt /> <!-- closing v-stepper here does not work, -->
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

How to achieve this goal? (I am not asking for an implementation, just a hint/idea/alternative)

Answer (score 1):

wrap your `v-stepper` component with a div like `<div class="sticky"><v-stepper/></div>`

and add the following rules to your css :

```
  .sticky {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: That did not work, however I used your idea in a different way, and I half-reached my goal. Thank you very much for the feedback  (and +1)

Comment: @BillalBegueradj i think setting  `<div ><div class="sticky"><v-stepper/></div><v-app>...</div>` should work

Answer (score 1):

```
.v-stepper__wrapper {
    height: auto !important;
}
```